# Is it possible to get modulo equivalent if a fraction involves irrational numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864568/is-it-possible-to-do-modulo-of-a-fraction) answers how to get modulo for a fraction but mostly rational numbers are addressed.

Therefore: $\frac{7}{8} \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$

What is the value of $r$ in the following Type of fractions? Is it defined?

$\frac{7}{\sqrt{8}} \equiv r \pmod{7}$

$\frac{7}{\sqrt{7}} \equiv r \pmod{7}$

Comment: I would say those expressions are ill defined because the square root is ill defined.  Is $\sqrt 2 \pmod 7$ $3$ or $4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question isn't really about fractions with irrational denominators, it's about modular arithmetic for irrationals. The answer to that question is that it's not customary to write expressions like
$$
\sqrt{99} \pmod 4 .
$$
Modular arithmetic is usually reserved for integers, and for fractions with some integral denominators, as in the linked question.

In some computer languages and in some applications you might see
$$
\sqrt{99} = 9.94987437107\ldots = 1.94987437107\pmod 4 .
$$
The answer is the number between $0$ and $4$ that differs from 
$\sqrt{99}$ by a multiple of $4$.

**Edit**. As @lulu notes, you may want to think about the square root as an operation on the residues. Then for example 
$$
\sqrt{2} \pmod{7} 
$$
is $3$ or $4$ since each of those when squared gives an answer congruent to $2 \pmod{7}$.